# R shinymanager removeTab after authentication

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, reactive

I would like to hide the "Login" tabPanel and render the content of the "Content" tabPanel after the user was able to authenticate into the app.

The content of the "Content" tabPanel is indeed rendered but the "Login" tabPanel is not removed. I don't understand why this is happening.

Here the code to reproduce the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

# Credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("test"),
  password = c(scrypt::hashPassword("test")),
  is_hashed_password = TRUE
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Test project",
  id="main",
  tabPanel(
    "Login",
    auth_ui(
      id="auth",
      lan=use_language("fr")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "Content",
    uiOutput("test")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  auth <- callModule(
    module = auth_server,
    id = "auth",
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  reactive({
    req(auth$result)
    removeTab(
      inputId = "main",
      target = "Login"
    )
  })
  output$test <- renderUI({
    req(auth$result)
    tags$h1("Test")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `reactive` on its own, put into the `observer`, since the reactive expression needs to be called by something or invoked by another expression, otherwise it wont be executed:

```
  observe({
    req(auth$result)
    removeTab(
      inputId = "main",
      target = "Login"
    )
  })
```